# How to Visible Group Header While Scrolling in Tablix Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

While working with Tablix Report I want to visible Group header while scrolling

I tried `Fixed Data = True` but not working for me. BTW, First header row is working fine by changes of show scroll bar. (FixedData property to True in Advanced Mode) but not the **this** one row.

[image]

*Kindly provide me the solution.*

Comment: here I have added all tags. the reason is if someone has only set `ssrs-2008` as favorite tags then this question may not  be read by those people. this is a common for all ssrs that's why I have added all tags together. @oceans

Answer (score 1):

In SSRS 2008 R2, I managed a workaround using **subreports**.

- Make a report that shows the data for a single group, based on a parameter.

  - Put all the headers you want on this report's tablix, and make them fixed with `FixedData = True`.
  - Use the parameter to set what will appear in the group-specific header text.
- Make a separate report that will get every group.

  - Create a table grouped by your group, with one cell.
  - Put a Subreport in the cell, and pass the group to the subreport's parameter.

[image: Main report and sub-report]

This worked for me in the Visual Studio preview, and viewing a deployed version on IE and Chrome, and hopefully will work in your environment too.

The catch is you'll see the main report header repeated for each group. However I tried to add this to the main report and it seemed to confuse matters, functioning differently in preview, IE and Chrome.

[image]